# How to make .NET embedded web browsers accept complex HTML+JS content

Tags: .net, webview, browser, windows-runtime

I'm experimenting with Windows 8 "Modern" application programming. What I want to do is use a WinRT WebView component to host a map rendered by the [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) web mapping API.

I created a small "Metro"/C# application which hosts a WebView as the main UI component. I also created a simple HTML page which uses OpenLayers. When I open this HTML page in IE or Chrome in Win8, the page renders correctly, i.e. the sample map appears.

When I run the "Metro" app, nothing appears, and no errors are displayed or logged. Nothing.

I switched to a simple WinForms app, thinking that either my understanding of WinRT is immature or there is something wrong in the HTML (although why it displays in both browsers...)

When I run the WinForms app, I do get an error. A dialog appears, which contains:

"An error has occurred in the script on this page."
Error:  Syntax error
URL:    about:OpenLayers.js

After some google searches, I come across a Microsoft IE extension called "[mark of the web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" (at this point, I'm thinking "mark of the devil" is more appropriate). Apparently if you want to host a web page containing "active content" in IE, you must annotate your HTML content with a marker indicating that it is OK to. Basically, a suitably formatted HTML comment must occur in the first 2048 bytes of the HTML content.

For my situation, the appropriate "mark of the web" would appear to be:

"saved from url=(0014)about:internet"

I placed it as an HTML comment as the first element in the  section.

It makes no difference. Same error occurs when I run the WinForms app. Of course, all is OK when I run IE.

The issue has something to do with enhanced IE security (I won't specify the details here). MS has made it much harder (!!!) to use web pages which contain "active content", especially if the web pages are being displayed from locally caches, as opposed to being fetched from a web server. There's even [a complete site](http://markoftheweb.net/) for dealing with some of the issues.

And, I'm at something of a loss as to how to proceed. I've tried changing IE's security settings to allow "active content", I've used "mark of the web" with and without changing security settings. Nothing appears to work.

So, does anybody in SO have any experience with dealing with this? This is really baffling me.

Comment: A suggestion from another site was to use a file-based URL, i.e. a file/// specification to the html file. This worked for the WInForms based app, but does nothing for the WinRT app. Interesting

Comment: WinRT documentation suggests that this can't be done directly by reading local content. Need to investigate building in the HTML and JS as app content.